# Getting data from different days

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have 7 column in my table "users". The columns are like this:

```
ac0 // Represents clicks made today
ac1 // Represents clicks made from ac0
ac2 // Represents clicks made from ac1
ac3 // Represents clicks made from ac2
ac4 // Represents clicks made from ac3
ac5 // Represents clicks made from ac4
ac6 // Represents clicks made from ac5
```

I have to show this in a chart, that is build up like this:

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['Today', 'Yesterday', '12-08', '11-08','10-08','09-08','08-08']
},
series: [{
name: 'Clicks',
data: [1,4,5,2,6,4,6]
}]
```

As you can see, I have to insert the `ac#` into the `data:[]` field, and then add a date to each, to insert in the `categories:[]`.

How can this be obtained?

Comment: None so far, as I am in doubt.

Comment: I don't undestud if ac1 data is from yesterday or from tomorow, ac2 is from two day ago or two days after today, and so on.

Comment: I also do not figure how your db model works (or shift values) on midnight. but it is not important to give you an anwser

Comment: I will run a cronjob every midnigt, and update so:
ac0 value becomes ac1 etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to populate "categories" and "data" it's even easier:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('test') or die('Could not select database');

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = 'SELECT ac0, ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4, ac5, ac6 FROM users WHERE id = 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        $data = $row;
    }

    $days = array('Today', 'Yesterday');
    for ($i=2; $i<7;$i++)
    {
        $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-'.$i.' day'));
    }
?>
xAxis: {
categories: ['<?php echo implode("', '", $days); ?>']
},
series: [{
name: 'Clicks',
data: [<?php echo implode(',', $data)?>]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works. Although, I changed the $i+1 to $i+0, as ac0 represents TODAYS clicks.

Thanks again!

Comment: yes, you're right, and you can remove the "+0" thing and leave is as "$i". I'm updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate an img with the graph you can use pChart2, a php library that generates graph:
[image: graph generated by pchart]

Here is the code that generated the graph above:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('test') or die('Could not select database');

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = 'SELECT ac0, ac1, ac2, ac3, ac4, ac5, ac6 FROM users WHERE id = 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        $data = $row;
    }

    // Free resultset
    mysql_free_result($result);

        // Closing connection
    mysql_close($link);

    // include pChart library
    include("pchart/class/pData.class.php");
    include("pchart/class/pDraw.class.php");
    include("pchart/class/pImage.class.php");

    $MyData = new pData();
    // Add point to the graph
    $MyData->addPoints($data, "clicks");

    // Configure Axis labels
    $MyData->setAxisName(0, "Clicks");
    $MyData->addPoints(array('Today', 'Yesterday', '12-08', '11-08', '10-08', '09-08', '08-08'), "Labels");
    $MyData->setSerieDescription("Labels", "Days");
    $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");

    // Generate bar chart
    $myPicture = new pImage(700, 230, $MyData);
    $myPicture->setGraphArea(60, 60, 600, 200);
    $myPicture->drawScale(array("DrawSubTicks" => TRUE));
    $myPicture->setShadow(TRUE, array("X" => 1, "Y" => 1, "R" => 0, "G" => 0, "B" => 0, "Alpha" => 10));
    $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName" => "pchart/fonts/verdana.ttf", "FontSize" => 6));
    $myPicture->setShadow(FALSE);
    $myPicture->drawBarChart(array("DisplayValues" => TRUE, "DisplayColor" => DISPLAY_MANUAL, "DisplayR"=>0, "DisplayG"=>0,"DisplayB"=>0, "Rounded" => TRUE, "Surrounding" => 60));

    /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
    $myPicture->render("img/mygraph.png");

    echo '<img src="img/mygraph.png" />';
```